# rotateY doesn't work when use jquery .css()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to give the .front div a flip effect when click the button.  But somehow when I added the jquery .css(), I will not be able to see the flip effect.  if i call this `console.log($(greenstuff).css('left'));` after set .css(), it will work.  How come?   I need the container to add perspective attr, anyway i can fix this?  thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/do2owwnk/44/

html:

```
<div class="front">
    <p>!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!FRONT</p>
</div>

<br></br>
<button class="but" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

css:

```
.front {
        transition: 2s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
        position:relative;
        backface-visibility: hidden;

        background-color:green;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 320px;
        height: 250px;
        margin-left: 0,
        margin-top: 0,
    }
    .but {
        position:absolute;
        top: 300px;
    }
```

javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    //greenstuff is the div to flip
    var greenstuff = document.querySelector(".front");
    //creating a div
    var container = $('<div></div>');

    container.css({
        position: 'absolute',
            width: '320px',
            height: '250px',
        perspective:'800px'
    });
    container.insertBefore(greenstuff);
    $(greenstuff).appendTo(container);

    $(greenstuff).css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    left: 0,
                    top: 0,
                    'margin-left': 0,
                    'margin-top': 0
                });

    //if you uncomment this line of code, it will work, why?
    //console.log($(greenstuff).css('left'));

    greenstuff.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";

}
```

Comment: css syntax note: css properties don't get quoted. Only property values with non-word-characters do (spaces, dashes, etc). So it's `margin-left`, not `'margin-left'`. The JavaScript equivalent is the camelcased version, so on the JS side it's `marginLeft`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that is not correct. You can't define an object key with a hyphen in it if it  isn't quoted. jQuery also accepts camelCase so object keys don't need quoting as you point out ...but it's still arbitrary to quote or not quote, and both approaches work

Comment: @charlietfl sure but you will note OP's actual CSS has quoted properties (not just their JS), which is what the comment was on.

Comment: @charlietfl not sure what that comment applies to, but CSS in a stylesheet block or in its own .css file does not use quoted properties. The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) is pretty clear on that.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my bad, I did miss looking at the actual css and was focused on the js properties

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks, i made the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    greenstuff.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(180deg)";
});
```

### -DEMO-

#### requestAnimationFrame

#### polyfill

#### caniuse

Answer (score 0):

In the JSFiddle, if you comment out the following lines

```
//container.insertBefore(greenstuff);
//$(greenstuff).appendTo(container);
```

Then it works without having to uncomment the console.log() call. Clearly, this causes the green box to "jump" a bit as it is no longer repositioned within the generated container.

Can you revisit the necessity to create the "container" object?

Comment: I kinda need the container to add perspective, and it's also need by other parts of my project. Thanks for your help!